# What is necessary for using const in Objective-C for declaring values that aren't to change?

Tags: objective-c, constants

I've been using `#define` in my .m file for awhile now and I've recently found out that it's not preferable and you should be using `const`. However, there's a lot of information about using consts out there that varies greatly, and I want to make sure I'm using them properly.

For my `#define`s, I just used them in my .m because I didn't really see any reason for them to be public. But in most cases consts seem to be declared in the .h with an `extern` or `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` preceding it.

Is it good practice to do it in the header? Or is it alright to just do it in the implementation?

Also, is prepending `static` necessary?

Does `const` come before the type, like `NSString * const` or `const NSString *`?

And is there an accepted standard for how to name them? It seems like there's a lot of conflicting beliefs there, as some people stick with prepending `k`, some people use three letter constants, some don't at all, and some use camel case starting with an capital letter.

Answer (score 6):

If it's public – a part of a class or module's interface – then the declaration should be in the header. The definition should be in the implementation, though.

Specifying `static` gives the symbol internal linkage. You should use it for private symbols but you must not use it for public ones.

`NSString * const` and `const NSString *` mean two different things. The first is a constant pointer to an `NSString`.  The second is a pointer to a constant `NSString`. Although it's somewhat non-intuitive, you should use the former.

You **definitely** want the pointer to be constant. You don't want somebody to be able to assign to the pointer, making it point to something different.

You might expect that you also want the `NSString` to be constant, too (i.e. `const NSString * const`), but that is not a good idea. First, since `NSString` is already immutable, it's unnecessary. Nobody will be able to change the content of the `NSString` object. Beyond that, an `NSString` may still change some of its internal state over time, without changing its value. For example, it might cache a representation in a particular encoding. (`NSString` literals don't actually do anything like this, but you don't want to preclude it.)

As to naming conventions, that's a matter of style and not really something that can be answered definitively.

Finally, for integer constants, you should consider using an enumeration rather than a `const` variable. The elements of an enumeration can be used as true compile-time constants, such as in `case`s of `switch` statements.

Comment: I give you a +1 because you explained very well why the `NSString` object itself should *not* be `const`. Another obvious example is retaining and releasing the string. When an object is retained, its reference counter is still adjusted, regardless of whether or not the class is conceptually mutable or immutable. This can't be done with a `const` struct.

Answer (score 1):

With `#define` you don't get type checking as the they are nothing but preprocessor directives.

Using const will not only help avoid type errors but also help you in debugging.

`static` will make sure your const is only visible to the code in the current file.

For primitive types use

```
static const int kSomeInt = 10;
```

For objects use

```
static NSString *const kSomeString = @"Const";
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does const come before the type, like NSString * const or const NSString *?

A good rule of thumb here is to read from right to left.

I.E:

> NSString * const

A constant pointer to a NSString object.

> const NSString *

A pointer to a constant NSString. You could write this:

> NSString const *

And it would mean the same thing.